# Can a property of a database in an availability group be changed without dropping the database from the AG?

Tags: sql-server

The database is in Always ON and having size of 3.4 TB. Now the application team want to change property  `is_broker =1`.

I  want to make sure that we can rejoin the database on secondary without restoring the database again.

Comment: What version of SQL Server? There are five settings related to service_broker; which one are you planning to change?

Answer (score 0):

> [...] i want to make sure how can we rejoin the database on secondary without restoring the database again.

So long as the log on the primary holds enough information for the database on the secondary to find a common point, you shouldn't have to restore the database.

Even so, you wouldn't have to restore the *whole* database, just the latest log backups that span the gap, and then can be joined again.